# Two Points distance, Haskell without changing function declaration?

Tags: haskell

For the distance between two Points, without changing the function declaration, I keep getting this error "Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:"

```
type Point a = (a,a)
distance :: (Real a, Floating b) => Point a -> Point a -> b
distance (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy))
  where dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
```

Comment: have you tried applying `realToFrac` to the result of `sqrt`?

Answer (score 2):

`sqrt` returns the same type as its argument:

```
Prelude> :t sqrt
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

Since you're providing `b` as argument to `sqrt`, Haskell deduces that the return type must be `b` and not `a`.

Is there a specific reason why you cannot use

```
distance :: Floating b => Point b -> Point b -> b
distance (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy))
  where dx = x2 - x1
        dy = y2 - y1
```

Comment: It is required in my assignment, that I am not supposed to change the function header, as we are supposed to use the tester provided to us

Comment: @Sal you can easily wrap this function to achieve the original signature, since you can convert `Point a` to `Point b` whenever `Real a` and `Fractional b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Point a = (a,a)
distance :: (Real a, Floating b) => Point a -> Point a -> b
distance (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy))
  where dx = realToFrac $ x2 - x1
        dy = realToFrac $ y2 - y1
```

Comment: This is now the correct solution, but IMO “here have the working code” answers are not great to homework questions.

Comment: its not the exact answer I m looking for, and this was just a small function from the a larger project